# How to post special characters to Amazon SQS using WSO2

Tags: amazon-sqs, wso2-esb

we are trying to post json data to Amazon SQS which has special characters. But we are receiving exception while inserting data stating json is malformed. Following is the payload we have tested. [{ "ns2:Operation": { "core": { "system": "Local", "parameters": [{ "name": "name", "value": "qwerty" }, { "name": "operation", "value": "test" }, ], "actionDate": "11/12/2018", }, "ns2:action": "TESTING", "@xmlns:ns2": "http://test-app/testwebservice", "@xmlns": "http://test-app/testwebservice", } }]

Comment: wrong json. check it on https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks,i forgot remove commas while uploading. This is the JSON [{ "ns2:Operation": { "core": { "system": "Local", "parameters": [{ "name": "name", "value": "qwerty" }, { "name": "operation", "value": "test" } ], "actionDate": "11/12/2018" }, "ns2:action": "TESTING", "@xmlns:ns2": "http://test-app/testwebservice", "@xmlns": "http://test-app/testwebservice" } }]

Comment: In this case json is perfectly valid.What do you mean special character?

Comment: Hi Simar, here we have '@' symbol. if we are removing '@', the json gets processed

Comment: Can you provide stack trace or error or code example or library used to parse json. Since json is valid, this reduce problem to code that handle this json.

Comment: What API call are you making? From an SQS perspective, SQS doesn't care if it's json or not, it's just a string blob of data - can be anything. Are you getting a stack trace or error message?

Comment: Hi Simar and Krease, following is the error we are getting "Existing jso
n payload is malformed. MessageID : urn:uuid:9e4c40c4-1ccd-4a6d-80ed-86ed462d7f89 org.apache.synapse.commons.SynapseCommonsException: Existing json payload is malformed. Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Illegal character: <\> Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Illegal character: <\> Caused by: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Illegal character: <\>"

Comment: It is unclear on which stage you are getting an error.  If message comes to WSO from Amazon SQS, check part places malformed json into queue. If wso sends json to amazon sql then it is nothing to do with queue, either you are unable to build a valid json either, if wso in between with some source of json and queue, check the source of json. Just a guess, do you use payload mediator?